# Projection query with new fields/properites ignores entries that haven't set those properties yet

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I have an `Article` type structured like this:

```
type Article struct {
    Title    string
    Content  string `datastore:",noindex"`
}
```

In an administrative portion of my site, I list all of my Articles.  The only property I need in order to display this list is `Title`; grabbing the content of the article seems wasteful. So I use a [projection query](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/projectionqueries):

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("Article").Project("Title")
```

Everything works as expected so far.  Now I decide I'd like to add two fields to `Article` so that some articles can be unlisted in the public article list and/or unviewable when access is attempted.  Understanding the datastore to be schema-less, I think this might be very simple.  I add the two new fields to `Article`:

```
type Article struct {
    Title    string
    Content  string `datastore:",noindex"`

    Unlisted   bool
    Unviewable bool
}
```

I also add them to the projection query, since I want to indicate in the administrative article list when an article is publicly unlisted and/or unviewable:

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("Article").Project("Title", "Unlisted", "Unviewable")
```

Unfortunately, this only returns entries that have explicitly included `Unlisted` and `Unviewable` when `Put` into the datastore.

My workaround for now is to simply stop using a projection query:

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("Article")
```

All entries are returned, and the entries that never set `Unlisted` or `Unviewable` have them set to their zero value as expected.  The downside is that the article content is being passed around needlessly.

In this case, that compromise isn't terrible, but I expect similar situations to arise in the future, and it could be a big deal not being able to use projection queries.  Projections queries and adding new properties to datastore entries seem like they're not fitting together well.  I want to make sure I'm not misunderstanding something or missing the correct way to do things.

1. It's not clear to me from the documentation that projection queries should behave this way (ignoring entries that don't have the projected properties rather than including them with zero values).  Is this the intended behavior?
2. Are the only options in scenarios like this (adding new fields to structs / properties to entries) to either forgo projection queries or run some kind of "schema migration", `Get`ting all entries and then `Put`ing them back, so they now have zero-valued properties and can be projected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projection queries source the data for fields from the indexes not the entity, when you have added new properties pre-existing records do not appear in those indexes you are performing the project query on. They will need to be re-indexed.

You are asking for those specific properties and they don't exist hence the current behaviour.

You should probably think of a projection query as a request for entities with a value in a requested index in addition to any filter you place on a query.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a bit.  Is the only (or best) way to get everything re-indexed to `Get` and then `Put` all existing entities? I see myself adding a "schema" version number to the datastore and doing migrations like that when adding fields to structs, but I'm worried I might be straying from best practices with that. Is it really unusual to add fields?  Is there a best practice for updating indexes so projection queries can work?

Comment: I found [this article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema), which clarified for me that: yes, the best practice is to `Get` and `Put` all old entries, probably via the Task Queue API.  Thanks.

Comment: Another strategy I have seen, is to fire off a task queue request to reindex specific entities when you retrieve an entity that doesn't have the current schema version, though that wouldn't be that helpful if your doing projection queries.